# Selenium Grid - Start test on Linux VM

Tags: java, linux, selenium, automated-tests

i have a problem starting a Selenium Test from my Windows 10 Host to a Linux VM.
On the VM I started the Hub and registered a Node. 
Im also able to access the Selenium Grid Interface from my Host.

Do I have to start the Geckodriver manually or have to install the driver on the VM?

I use Selenium Standalone 3.5.3 and my Firefox-Version on my VM is 52.2.0.

*This is my java class where I want to trigger the test*

```
    package service;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.net.URL;

public class TestTest {

  private static WebDriver driver;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("driver.gecko.driver", "src/main/resources/geckodriver.exe");

    String Node = "http://192.168.20.206:4444/wd/hub";
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), capabilities);

    driver.navigate().to("http://www.DemoQA.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();

  }
}
```

*And this is my stacktrace*

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51403', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'linux-3rfg', ip: 'Unknown', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.76-1-default', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 81 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
    at service.TestTest.main(TestTest.java:21)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z'
System info: host: 'linux-3rfg', ip: 'Unknown', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.76-1-default', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MINERVA', ip: '192.168.20.83', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.lambda$new$0(ServicedSession.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:173)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$createSession$16(ActiveSessionFactory.java:171)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.createSession(ActiveSessionFactory.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51403', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the gecko driver path when you register the node as given below and download and keep the driver file in a drive.

> java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver= -jar  -role node -hub http://192.168.20.206:4444/grid/register

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Where do you got this information? I spent so much time on searching...